# Can't run qt Demos of qt because Cocoa plugin is not found - Macos

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, conan

i'm trying to run a binary using the qt Lib, qt was downloaded from Conan and binary built from Cmake, here is the error log i get when i try to run it :

```
$/bin/babel_client
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

[1]    77319 abort      ./bin/babel_client
```

I have a qt.conf file generated by Cmake to the path of the qt conan install path, here is it :

```
[Paths]
Prefix=/Users/laurent/.conan/data/qt/5.15.2/_/_/package/47ddefeb00b7880a55cbefeb04ea1dc3d0f4a43e
```

I already tried to reinstall `python-opencv-headless` from pip3

Here is my CMakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(BABEL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(build/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

# Set path for FindXXX.cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# Important for Qt
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

file(WRITE ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/qt.conf [Paths]\nPrefix=${CONAN_QT_ROOT})

# Packages
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(portaudio REQUIRED)
find_package(Opus REQUIRED)

# Compilation Client
set(BABEL_CLIENT_EXECUTABLE babel_client)
set(BABEL_CLIENT_LIBRARIES
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Network
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Gui
    opus
)
include(./client/build_client.cmake)

build_client()


# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui)
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opus)

# if (WIN32)
#     target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio_x64)
# else()
#     target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio)
# endif()
```

Do you have any idea on what's wrong ?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but the cocoa plugin is not installed? Is that pip package for opencv supposed to install a Qt plugin? I doubt it.

Comment: Yeah, I find it weird, but some solutions on it talked about installing opencv so I don't Know

Comment: did you run `macdeployqt` on your app?

Comment: I don't think i can, because the project has to be built from a single command line, so it has to be installed threw conan and not threw qtCreator

Comment: For what it's worth, I am now having this issue too and can't seem to find much around it online apart from this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/98816/qt-could-not-find-the-platform-plugin-cocoa/11 which says to reinstall Qt.

Comment: @geeks_kick I ended up giving up on this, a friend and I exchanged our tasks so we could continue to work, since I had a similar issue with Conan and macos, I would recommend you to make sure that your project compile correctly and runs on the target machine like a linux machine, test it out via docker for example, then once your base is ok, install qt manually on your mac, to the exact same version of your conanfile. We could pm if you would like to talk about it.